# Custom spacing between instances?

Tags: geometry-nodes, instances

Is it possible to use a repeating, or customized, spacing between instances?

For example, the geometry nodes below space the instances out evenly, but what nodes would be needed to create this A/B/A/B type repeating spacing between the instances?
[image: Base nodes]

I've been looking around and have only found these nodes below that hide every 3rd instance:[image: incorrect option]

... but that's not what I'm looking for and am hoping to show all the instances with just the space between them altered.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found another solution that fits what I'm trying to do by using an accumulate field.  I've attached the node layout below and highlighted the editable A and B distances.

There's also the excellent solution put forth by quellenform above.

Thanks! This question is answered.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution could look like this:

[image]

- First create a `Mesh Line` whose *Offset* equals $A+B$.
- With the help of the node `Duplicate Elements` this line is then simply duplicated.
- The *Duplicate Index* is then queried with `Compare`, which marks the points of the duplicated line and then move them with `Set Position`.
- Finally you can remove the last point again with a `Compare` node, using the number of total points.

---

An even simpler alternative would be this one:

[image]

- First create a `Mesh Line` whose *Offset* equals $A+B$.
- Then subdivide this line with `Subdivide Mesh`, which gives you more points in between, but with higher indices.
- Compare these indices with a `Compare` node and move the points with `Set Position`.

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.2+)*</sub>

Comment: Brilliant solutions! Thanks for this!